# How to create a list with the n last months in sqlite?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

is it possible to create a list with the n last months in sqlite?

The output should be:

```
2016-01
2015-12
2015-11
2015-10
2015-09
...
```

Thanks for your answers in advance. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible with a recursive [common table expression](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html):

```
WITH RECURSIVE months(m) AS (
  SELECT strftime('%Y-%m', 'now')
  UNION ALL
  SELECT strftime('%Y-%m', m || '-01', '-1 month')
  FROM months
  LIMIT 5
)
SELECT m FROM months;
```

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I was looking for. Not as nice as in Oracle but working. :-)